# Given Time in minutes, print it in hours and minutes

Tags: python

In Question,  Given Time is in minutes that requires to be converted into hours and minutes.

Sample :

Input - 53
Output - 0 53

```
num = int(input())
if num < 60:
    print('0'+" "+str(num))
else:
    if num>=60:
        time = num*(1/60)
        time1 = (format(time, '.2f'))
        print(str(time1).replace('.',' '))
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: `hours, minutes = divmod(num, 60)`.

Comment: You may want to ask a question. Right now your post doesn't contain any.

Comment: Please care about clearly stating your question and include research effort for future questions. Else they will recive bad score. This problem could have been easily answered with google and some ingenuity.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, 
I will follow that next time.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is using integer division (`//`) and modulo (`%`):

```
def printAsHoursAndMinutes(timeInMinutes):
    hours = timeInMinutes // 60
    minutes = timeInMinutes % 60
    print("{} {}".format(hours, minutes)) #edited to match the requested output format
```

`//` will return the integer part of the devision, `%` returns the rest. With 130 as input, the above code will print "2 10", for 5 as input, it prints "0 5".

[Edit:] This works for any nonegative integer. If you want to support negative integers too, add the following condition just before the print:

```
if(timeInMinutes < 0):
    hours = hours + 1
    minutes = 60 - minutes
```

This allows us to handle inputs like -65 to print "-1 5".

For floating point numbers, things migth get a bit ugly because `%` is not 100% acurate (e.g. `60.1` results in `1.0 0.10000000000000142`). This even happenes when using `divmod` as mentioned by @CristiFati in the comments to the question, so there is no real way around it and we'd need a more advanced handling or a custom modulo method but that is off-topic here.

Comment: Propably for it's brevity. I edited in an explanation and an example but ther really is nothing else to say about this problem.

Comment: @hajef The solution should return 0 5 as output when 5 is given input alone.

Comment: I double checked it. If you change the string at line 4 to "{} {}", you get these results: 5 -> "0 5", 60 -> "1 0", 65 -> "1 5". Google "python integer division" and "python modulo operator" if you don't understand how this code works and cut the "python" if you don't understand the approach iitself. This can't be put in a more easy way. It's the same thing that [dicmod](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/divmod) does for integer input.

Answer (score -1):

As per shown in picture...

You may try this..

```
def HoursandMinutes(Minutes):
    Minutes = Minutes % (24*3600)
    Hour = Minutes // 60
    Minutes %= 60
    print("%d %d" % (Hour, Minutes))
```

When you call this function

OUTPUT

```
HoursandMinutes(52)
0 52

HoursandMinutes(70)
1 10

HoursandMinutes(90)
1 30 

HoursandMinutes(105)
1 45
```

Comment: Why did you decide that times over 60 days should create unexpectad behaviour? Use `Minutes = Minutes % (24*60)` at line 2 if you want to cut every day but I don't think this is the intention of the question. 1500 Minutes are 25 hours and 0 minutes - not 1 houre and 0 minutes. And as I sayed `Minutes = Minutes % (24*3600)` produces this hickup at 60 days (since we have input in minutes, not seconds). Try 86400 or any larger input to see it yourself.